# OAuth2 on AWS Elastic Beanstalk - CORS error

Tags: php, angularjs, amazon-web-services, oauth, laravel-5

I've deployed a working Angular frontend 1.4, and Laravel 5.1 API project to AWS S3 (static frontend) and AWS Elasticbeanstalk respectively.

I'm using [OAuth2 for Laravel 5.1](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel/tree/master/docs#readme) and this works quite nicely locally. When I deploy, I get a CORS error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://my-api-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com/1.0/me/4/dashboard. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin
>   'http://my.staging.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com' is
>   therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 400.

My Angular app handles the auth token, but just to test it out elsewhere, I first posted to `my-api-staging.elasticbeanstalk.com/1.0/oauth/access_token` through DHC which got me a token.

Normally with this token I can request data from any endpoint, but if I try to request data from the staging site on AWS, I get rejected:

> {
>   "error": "invalid_request",
>   "error_description": "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an invalid parameter value, includes a parameter more than once, or is otherwise malformed. Check the \"access token\" parameter."
>   }

I haven't seen any additional setup for AWS for OAuth2. Did I miss something?